# Why is onPress listed as an event in the documentation of marker in react-native-maps?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am a person who recently started learning react native and I was under the impression that everything that was passed, was a prop. But when I was looking at the documentation of a Marker , onPress was listed under Events and not under props. The documentation of a button clearly enlists onPress under the props heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> Most components can be customized when they are created, with different parameters. These creation parameters are called props. Basically anything between the angle brackets of a component can be viewed as a prop.

If you notice for the Button documentation, onPress is a prop but it's also an event!

Props

- onPress
- accessibilityLabel
- color
- disabled
- testID
- hasTVPreferredFocus

In the example below, onPress, title, color and accessibilityLabel are all props.

```
<Button
    onPress={onPressLearnMore}
    title="Learn More"
    color="#841584"
    accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
/>
```

What's cool about making an event a prop is that you can delegate or pass an event from the main or parent component to a sub component.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button

You can think of props in the same way as passing parameters to a function.  In JavaScript you can pass a function as a parameter, so being able to pass an event handler (a function) makes sense.